# 'node.js': Does it need to be run a server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been following a tutorial http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2014/restful-web-app-node-express-mongodb/ and I would recommend this to anyone that is just getting started with building web applications with node.js.  I'm a bit slower though, I guess.  So I wanted to see if the javaScript files created for the application need to be placed on a server.  I do have access to one, and I've searched the web and stackoverflow for this, and what I found was that node.js is a 'javascript runtime';, but I don't completely understand what that means.  I think it means that I don't need to put it on a server, but I just need to some advice from someone with experience.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is javascript that is hosted on the server. This is what is run by the server. There are also client files that the server code can send to a requester. The simple case is when the server and client are the same computer. However in general they are different.

from [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/starter/hello-world.html). This is an example of "server code" that is intended to be run on the server.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);

});
```

if you then point your browser to http://localhost:3000/
you will get back a page that says

```
Hello World!
```

The server code is where you would tie into a mongodb server and would package up info to be sent to the client.

Comment: @alexcarll Does this make sense? Is there something you need more clarity on?